# ¿Cómo soluciono este error: ORA-28000 The account is locked en Oracle SQL?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

Lo que sucede es que estoy trabajando en un proyecto con *JSP*  y bases de datos *Oracle* con *Oracle SQL*. En la conexión estaba ingresando una contraseña incorrecta, lo que provocó que se bloqueara el *user* y era el único *user* que tenía registrado, así que no tengo cómo crear sentencias *SQL* ni tampoco tengo cómo desbloquearlo mediante sentencias.

¿Cómo se soluciona?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por si era el sys: F

Answer (score 0):

Pues te lo dice el mensaje. Contactando con el DBA (DataBase Administrator) o bien esperes un tiempo. El tiempo especificado en la DB para volver a intentarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad que la solución más rápida que encontré fue el reinstalar la base de datos Oracle.

Comment: Sí, lo mejor es hacer un procedimiento que cree las tablas, triggers, etc. y en estos casos volver a crearla. Y una vez en producción tener backups.